# Rust compiler thinks value returned by async block is `()`

Tags: asynchronous, rust

for some reason, the Rust compiler thinks `data` is `()`. `rust-analyzer` has the correct `Option<Vec<u8>>` that should be returned by the future.

```rust
let data: Option<Vec<u8>> = async_std::task::block_on(async {
    let file = rfd::AsyncFileDialog::new()
        .set_title("Import model")
        .add_filter("model files", &["glb", "gltf"])
        .pick_file().await;

    Some(file?.read().await)
});
```

when I build this, I get this error (with verbose flag):

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/main.rs:153:45
    |
153 |   ...   let data: Option<Vec<u8>> = async_std::task::block_on(async {
    |  _________________---------------___^
    | |                 |
    | |                 expected due to this
154 | | ...       let file = rfd::AsyncFileDialog::new()
155 | | ...           .set_title("Import model")
156 | | ...           .add_filter("model file", &["glb", "gltf"])
...   |
163 | | ...   });
    | |________^ expected `Option<Vec<u8>>`, found `()`
    |
    = note:   expected enum `std::option::Option<std::vec::Vec<u8>>`
            found unit type `()`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `bevy-shader-test` (bin "bevy-shader-test") due to previous error

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/codespace/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc --crate-name bevy_shader_test --edition=2021 src/main.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --diagnostic-width=134 --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=1 -C embed-bitcode=no -C debuginfo=2 -C debug-assertions=on -C metadata=4ec967b7cb826f26 -C extra-filename=-4ec967b7cb826f26 --out-dir /workspaces/bevy-shader-test/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/deps --target wasm32-unknown-unknown -C incremental=/workspaces/bevy-shader-test/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/incremental -L dependency=/workspaces/bevy-shader-test/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/deps -L dependency=/workspaces/bevy-shader-test/target/debug/deps --extern async_std=/workspaces/bevy-shader-test/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/deps/libasync_std-c42557917cecadcc.rlib --extern bevy=/workspaces/bevy-shader-test/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/deps/libbevy-198c54e8f15c5dab.rlib --extern bevy_egui=/workspaces/bevy-shader-test/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/deps/libbevy_egui-2acee9f13679c255.rlib --extern rfd=/workspaces/bevy-shader-test/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/deps/librfd-2f12fad211987389.rlib` (exit status: 1)
```

i have now found out that the cause of this issue is the `wasm32-unknown-unknown` target cfg in `async-std` [here](https://docs.rs/async-std/latest/src/async_std/task/block_on.rs.html#38). does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: What makes you think that the compiler thinks the returned value is `()`? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77759323/edit) your question to include the _full_ error message (from `cargo check`, not from your IDE).

Comment: @Jmb I added the error. the compiler explicitly mentions that the type is `()`.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman this example is reproducible in Rust 1.75.0.

Comment: Please refer to the docs I linked. By "minimal reproducible example", I mean the **smallest** piece of code that **we can run ourselves** that clearly demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman the additional context section i added should be runnable. the original example also produces the same error if `: Option<Vec<u8>>` is added to the `data` definition.

Comment: Compiles fine for me. Try `cargo clean`.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, you can replace `if file.is_none() { return None; } Some(file.unwrap().read()...` with just `Some(file?.read()...`

Comment: @ChayimFriedman `cargo clean`ing did not work. same error message as before.

Comment: @user4815162342 yeah I did that soon after posting, thanks for mentioning it though.

Comment: [Seems to compile just fine](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#LyoKW2RlcGVuZGVuY2llc10KYXN5bmMtc3RkID0gIioiCiovCgp1c2UgYXN5bmNfc3RkOjppbzo6UmVhZEV4dDsKCmZuIG1haW4oKSB7CiAgICBsZXQgZGF0YTogT3B0aW9uPFZlYzx1OD4+ID0gYXN5bmNfc3RkOjp0YXNrOjpibG9ja19vbihhc3luYyB7CiAgICAgICAgbGV0IGZpbGUgPSBhc3luY19zdGQ6OmZzOjpGaWxlOjpvcGVuKCJmb28iKS5hd2FpdC5vaygpOwogICAgICAgIAogICAgICAgIGxldCBtdXQgdiA9IFZlYzo6bmV3KCk7CiAgICAgICAgZmlsZT8ucmVhZF90b19lbmQoJm11dCB2KS5hd2FpdC51bndyYXAoKTsKICAgICAgICBTb21lKHYpCiAgICB9KTsKfQo=)

Comment: @PitaJ just did some testing, seems to be related to `wasm32-unknown-unknown`. building the example with that as a target reproduces the error.

Comment: edited question for readability and new question about workarounds. I could try sneaking the value out using channels but I'd rather use a different method if possible.

Comment: Note that the error message doesn't match the posted code: line 162 in the error message contains a closing brace that isn't in the posted code.

Comment: @Jmb I  believe that was from my previous example where I used a match statement instead of `file?`. I forgot to change the error when i changed the example.